# .htaccess prevent B flag from encoding + symbols or change occurences of %20 into +?

Tags: .htaccess

This line of my .htaccess file basically escapes and turns the first directory into a query string.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /a/?s=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

I did this mainly to escape & symbols, but it escapes all non alphanumeric characters, including '+' symbols. I don't want to escape these ones so that urls are more clean.

```
eat%20a%20pizza
```

I want:

```
eat+a+pizza
```

Is it possible to somehow replace '%20' with '+' or prevent the B flag from encoding then?

Comment: no I mean programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a way to be specific about how the `B` flag works, but you can change the `%20` back to `+` with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$ /$1+$2 [NE,L]
```

You're probably going to need to find the right place to put that, as it needs to loop in order to get rid of all the `%20`'s.