# Replacing %20 and dot with on all url in .htacess

Tags: php

I have many URLs in my PHP script, but I want to replace `%20` with `-` or `_`, and `.` with `-`.

Can I do this replacement globally using `.htacess`?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673576/replace-special-character-in-htaccess

Comment: It doesn't work for me.I don't know why.I have problem when I add dot to post it doesn't open with dot in post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess prevent B flag from encoding + symbols or change occurences of %20 into +?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791753/htaccess-prevent-b-flag-from-encoding-symbols-or-change-occurences-of-20-int)

Comment: You are spelling the name of the file--".htaccess" with two cs--correctly in your actual work, yes?